# Least Upper Bound and Great Lower Bound

Tags: real-analysis

> *Question:* Find the least upper bound and the greatest lower bound, if they exist, for the set: $f\Big((-4,-3]\cup[-1,2]\Big)$ where $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ is given by $f(x) =x ^2-4$

- So with the union I combined $(-4,2]$.
- I applied all those numbers in between in the function
- would my greatest lower bound be $1$ or $-3$ since $f(-1)=3$
- would my least upper bound be $-4$ or $12$. Since $f(-4)=12$ or would it not count because it’s under parentheses not []

If I’m doing something wrong please inform me!

Answer (score 1):

Your greatest lower bound $-4$ since that's the minimum value taken by the function in your interval. Your least upper bound is twelve because that's the highest value the function takes in your domain. In general, when a function is not monotonous, it may be that the greatest lower bounds or greatest upper bounds are not the endpoints of your interval or subintervals, but rather are often local extrema of your function.

Comment: I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The given set is the image of $(-4,-3]\cup [-1,2]$ by $f,$ which is simply (since $f$ is continuous) $(12,5]\cup[-3,0].$ It is then clear that the smallest upper bound is $12,$ and the biggest lower bound is $-3.$

Comment: Why isn’t it -4?